# Why does 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 3 == 244?

Tags: c#

Passing a value of "01200000131" to this method:

```
private static int sumOddVals(string barcode)
{
    int cumulativeVal = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < barcode.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("i is {0}; barcode{0} is {1}", i, barcode[i]));
            cumulativeVal += Convert.ToInt16(barcode[i]);
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Odd total is {0}", cumulativeVal));
    return cumulativeVal;
}
```

...returns "244"

I'm expecting it to return "4".

The first message box shows me what I'd expect to see, namely "1", then "0" three times, then "3", which I would expect to add up to "4", not "244".

Comment: Have you run it in the debugger to see what the values are in each pass?

Comment: `Convert.ToInt16(barcode[i])` will give you the ASCII value of the current character in the string.

Comment: @DStanley; yes, and I didn't know why those outsized vals were being generated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are converting numerical `char` values to `int`'s here:

```
 cumulativeVal += Convert.ToInt16(barcode[i]); // Indexer on a string is a char
```

What you want.. is to convert the string representation of that number into a number.. not the `char` value.. so add `ToString()`:

```
 cumulativeVal += Convert.ToInt16(barcode[i].ToString());
```

EDIT:

Or, as pointed out in the comments:

```
 cumulativeVal += Convert.ToInt16(barcode[i] - '0');
```

Result: 4.

Comment: Downvote for obtuse round-trip to a String just to convert an ASCII digit to an integer. All you need to do is `cumulativeVal += barcode[i]-'0'`. Or can you not do that in C#? It's been a while...

Comment: @SchighSchagh - That's good information, but I don't think it's worth a downvote.  Especially if you're not even sure it can be done in C#.

Comment: `Convert` performs sanity checks that your subtraction won't.

Comment: @SchighSchagh Quickly typed. I have edited the answer. I left `Convert` in for possible errors.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
    Convert.ToInt16(barcode[i])
```

Converts a `char` value (`barcode[i]`) into a `short`. But the character value is implicitly converted into an `int` before the call to `ToInt16()` anyway, so it is effectively converting the character code into its integer equivalent, i.e., into itself. Thus `'0'` gets converted into 48.

What you want is something like this:

```
    (barcode[i] - '0')
```

which works for all decimal digit characters (`'0'` through `'9'`).

**Warning**

If `barcode[i]` is not a decimal digit character, you will get strange results. (Your code should be checking for this anyway.)